# How can I execute an action after a model is created (.create & .bulk_create)

Tags: python, django, bulk, django-signals

Is there a preferred way of executing an action after a model instance is created in the database?

I know about signals. I know I can override the .save method. I know I can override the bulk one and atomically process each object in a transaction.

Is there anything like signals which trigger on model instance creation whatever the way of creation (even on bulk)? Thanks!

Comment: You may already know this, but you can also modify the [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) and [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/signals/#post-save) methods, as well as other pre/post method such as delete.

Comment: This question is opinion based.